# How to debug iOS native code in a flutter plugin?

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-plugin

I'm wonder how to debug flutter iOS code in a plugin?
I can open the example app that's generated whenever you create a plugin but I see the plugin code as binary framework, therefore I can't debug it.

For android it's fairly easy, I just open the android folder in A.S. and the plugin + the example are there, I just add run configs and I start debugging right away.

But I really hope to find a similar way for iOS.

Comment: Did you find a way finally? If so can you share with us please?

Comment: I successfuly debug ios code running directly from XCode

Answer (score 14):

Plugins are added to the ios app as pod projects so it is similar to debugging any code in pod project.

1. Open Runner project workspace
2. Browse the file in the Pods project
3. Put Breakpoint

NB: Need to run app from flutter first to work this properly

[image]

Comment: I am not able to see my plugin in Pods/Development Pods. I tried running the app on iOS first and then opened xcode but I am not able to see my plugin there.

Comment: Is the plugin in Development pod folder? else make sure the name is correct. In some case they may have used different library manager

Answer (score 5):

To set a breakpoint and debug Flutter plugin code from Xcode, try the following:

1. Open `ios/Runner.xcworkspace` for the Flutter application you want to debug.
2. From the *Debug* menu, select *Breakpoints* > *Create symbolic breakpoint...*
3. In the *Symbol* field, enter the method you want to break on. For example, to break on the default entrypoint for the plugin defined in the `HelloPlugin` class, set the symbol to `-[HelloPlugin handleMethodCall:result:]`.
4. Run your app from Xcode via *Product* > *Run*.

From that point, trigger the plugin code through whichever UI actions will hit the code in question.

Comment: flutter plugin should have 'example' subdir and use that application's `ios/Runner.xcworkspace` to run - also that application could have all basic functions of the plugin on a screen.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure to build the example app first using `cd hello/example; flutter build ios --no-codesign`, then open it in Xcode.

You can find files for the iOS part deep in the project hierarchy: *Pods > Development Pods > name_of_your_plugin > ... > Classes*

You can put breakpoints in the Xcode as you would normally do, and then you can run the example app straight from the Xcode.

[Reference](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/packages-and-plugins/developing-packages#step-2c-add-ios-platform-code-swifthm) from the Flutter team.

Comment: I am not able to see my plugin in Pods/Development Pods. I tried running the app on iOS first and then opened xcode but I am not able to see my plugin there.